# Table header taken from the list item used with ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, uirepeat

Let's say I have the following class Book

```
class Book{
    String author;
    String title;
}
```

I retrieve a list of Book ( `List<Book>` ) and I want to display it in a table like

```
author1:
    title1
    title11

author2:
    title2
    title22
    title222
```

I was thinking to create a hashmap mapping author => list of books but , as I have read in SO, hashmap is not supported in
h:datatable, nor in ui:repeat.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Thank you.

PS: I am using jsf 1.2

Feel free to suggest a better title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to adapt your data model in order to get it into a `h:dataTable`.

I suggest to create a class Author with a list of books:

```
class Author{
  String name;
  List<Book> books;
  ..
  // getters and setters
}
```

Then you can build a nested dataTable based on a `List<Author> authorList` (not tested):

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.authorList}" var="author">
  <h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{author.name}"/>
    <h:dataTable value="#{author.books}" var="book">
      <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{book.title}"/>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>  
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: Thanks, that s the way I took.